# Randomization of a parameterized class inside a class not working

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to use a parameterized class inside another class which I have to randomize.

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {
  TWO_LEGS,
  FOUR_LEGS,
  SIX_LEGS,
  EIGHT_LEGS
} leg_e;

typedef enum logic [2:0] {
  HUMAN,
  DOGS,
  CAT,
  ELEPHANT,
  FLY,
  COCKROACH,
  SPIDER
} animal_e;

class parameterized_class #( type enum_type);
  static int initial_allocation;
  static enum_type list[$];

  rand int unsigned ptr;

  constraint ptr_c {
            ptr < list.size();
  }

 function new();
   enum_type my_enum;
    if(initial_allocation == 0) begin
      initial_allocation = 1;
      for(int unsigned i = 0; i < my_enum.num(); i++)
        repeat($urandom_range(1,10)) list.push_back(my_enum);
    end
  endfunction
endclass

class random_class;
  rand parameterized_class#(leg_e) leg_select;
  rand parameterized_class#(animal_e) animal_select;

  rand leg_e leg_q[$];
  rand animal_e animal_q[$];

  constraint leg_animal_c {
      leg_select.list[leg_select.ptr] == TWO_LEGS -> animal_select.list[animal_select.ptr] inside {HUMAN};
      leg_select.list[leg_select.ptr] == FOUR_LEGS -> animal_select.list[animal_select.ptr] inside {DOGS, CAT, ELEPHANT};
      leg_select.list[leg_select.ptr] == SIX_LEGS -> animal_select.list[animal_select.ptr] inside {FLY, COCKROACH};
      leg_select.list[leg_select.ptr] == EIGHT_LEGS -> animal_select.list[animal_select.ptr] inside {SPIDER};
  }

  constraint q_c {
      leg_q.size() dist {[0:5] := 50, [6:10] := 50};
      animal_q.size() == leg_q.size();
      foreach(leg_q[i]) {
        leg_q[i] == leg_select.list[leg_select.ptr];
        animal_q[i] == animal_select.list[animal_select.ptr];
      }
  }
  function new();
    leg_select = new;
    animal_select = new;
  endfunction
endclass

module tb;
  initial begin
    random_class rnd = new;
    repeat (10) begin
      rnd.randomize();
      $display("Animals in queue = %p", rnd.animal_q);
      $display("Legs in queue = %p", rnd.leg_q);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

I am getting an error:
The solver will not solve for array 'animal_select.list' indexed by random 
  variable 'animal_select.ptr'.
  Please try to use a state variable, constant, or loop variable for array 
  index.

What modification I havee to make to get a result like:
{DOGS, CAT, HUMAN, ELEPHANT}
{FOUR_LEGS, FOUR_LEGS, TWO_LEGS, FOUR_LEGS, }

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over-thinking your problem. I think this code produces the result you are hoping for:

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {
  TWO_LEGS,
  FOUR_LEGS,
  SIX_LEGS,
  EIGHT_LEGS
} leg_e;

typedef enum logic [2:0] {
  HUMAN,
  DOGS,
  CAT,
  ELEPHANT,
  FLY,
  COCKROACH,
  SPIDER
} animal_e;


class random_class;
  rand leg_e leg_q[$];
  rand animal_e animal_q[$];

  constraint leg_animal_c {
    foreach (leg_q[i]) leg_q[i] == TWO_LEGS   -> animal_q[i] inside {HUMAN};
    foreach (leg_q[i]) leg_q[i] == FOUR_LEGS  -> animal_q[i] inside {DOGS, CAT, ELEPHANT};
    foreach (leg_q[i]) leg_q[i] == SIX_LEGS   -> animal_q[i] inside {FLY, COCKROACH};
    foreach (leg_q[i]) leg_q[i] == EIGHT_LEGS -> animal_q[i] inside {SPIDER};
  }

  constraint q_c {
    leg_q.size() dist {[0:5] := 50, [6:10] := 50};
      animal_q.size() == leg_q.size();
  }
endclass

module tb;
  initial begin
    random_class rnd = new;
    repeat (10) begin
      rnd.randomize();
      $display("Animals in queue = %p", rnd.animal_q);
      $display("Legs in queue = %p", rnd.leg_q);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3rh8

Comment: Agreed! But here my basic requirement is to have a parametrized class for different enum types and choose an element from that class using random variable "ptr". This will be helpful for my future code.

Comment: @Salim In which case, I think (if possible) you need to simplify your example a bit, because I already struggled for a long time to understand what it was you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I put a `$diplay()` debug in your code

```
foreach (list[i]) $display(list[i].name());
```

and see that your initialization is wrong. You always push the first enum into the list.
I changed your code to

```
  for(int unsigned i = 0; i < my_enum.num(); i++) begin
    /*repeat($urandom_range(1,10))*/ list.push_back(my_enum);
    my_enum = my_enum.next();
  end
```

and it does work. EDA code [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4A_S).

And why do all the queues have identical elements, it is because of your constraints

```
  foreach(leg_q[i]) {
    leg_q[i] == leg_select.list[leg_select.ptr];
    animal_q[i] == animal_select.list[animal_select.ptr];
  }
```